# Windows 10 doesn't warn before signing out

Tags: windows, windows-10

I just found out that Windows 10 do not warn when user does "Sign out"! My colleague just signed me out and it didn't warn him that I have applications open (like [R](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/)) and I lost some data! The opened R with unsaved scripts didn't warn either (but it warns when you close it normally!)

This is really bad!

There really should be a warning when apps are open and especially when some of them had unsaved data!

Any remedy for this? How to change Win 10 behaviour to get the warning?

Answer (score 3):

At logout, Windows sends a WM_QUIT message to each application, and it is each application's task to do so, or bring a popup asking the user to save, or do whatever it thinks appropriate. That process didn't change (relevantly) since Windows 95.

If one of your apps doesn't warn you, you can try to check if it has a setting for it, or use another app instead. Otherwise, locking your computer when you walk away prohibits others from logging you out too (unless they have admin rights).

Closing an app sends WM_CLOSE, and it's up to the app to react the same or different as to WM_QUIT. Finally, Windows can send WM_DESTROY, which is 'non-negotiable', but can be treated again differently by the app. Here are more details about the three messages: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3155782/what-is-the-difference-between-wm-quit-wm-close-and-wm-destroy-in-a-windows-pr

Comment: thanks, interesting information! It is interesting that the application (R) does warn when being closed directly; so is this a different than WM_QUIT? And regarding locking, I had TeamViewer session open to access this computer remotely, and during this computer isn't locked.

Comment: I don't know what the code is, but yes, Windows sends a different code than the normal quit as done in the application. Maybe I got it switched, and Windows sends WM_SHUTDOWN. Either way, it's the apps job to react to it.

Comment: @Aganju - Locking your computer will prevent being logged out, but it won't prevent another user, from rebooting the machine.  A group policy could prevent that though.

Answer (score 2):

> There really should be a warning when apps are open and especially when some of them had unsaved data!

It is entirely up to an application to prevent the automatic closure when a user is logged out.  Your colleague should have used **switch user** instead of logging you out.

Windows 10 by default, will warn you when you reboot a machine, if another user is logged in.  This is actually the only time a warning is generated by Windows.

> Any remedy for this? How to change Windows 10 behavior to get the warning?

Windows has never generated a warning like you describe, it has always been up to the application, to generate the warning or automatically perform a save.  Windows has ALWAYS closed applications when a user is logged out.  Any warnings you remember seeing were always generated by the application itself.

The behavior you describe is perfectly normal and cannot be prevented if a user logs out of another account instead of switching to their account.

Answer (score 1):

If you or another person signs out of your active account, there is no warning message. But anything that will close without saving may warn you of this (some do, some do not). So apparently the person signing you out was not paying attention. Check this. I looked for settings and did not see anything other than closing apps. Also, check to see if the apps remained active - some might do this also.

Comment: *"But anything that will close without saving will definitely warn you of this"* NO! THERE IS NO WARNING! Have you tried it? R (Rgui.exe) doesn't warn before signing out when having unsaved files, but it *does* warn when you directly close the application. Which means there is something wrong with the Windows sign out procedure, because it goes around this!

Comment: It varies with application. Some do and others not. I edited my answer. Most importantly users must pay attention when signing out

Comment: Looking now at a machine at a client and for Office and most other apps, there will definitely be a warning at sign out allowing you to cancel the sign out. Misbehaved apps may not honor this but good one do honor the sign out process